# Why is my select element hiding proceeding elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently trying to style a responsive form using bootstrap. This form actually didn't have any responsive design applied within a separate css file before applying bootstrap, everything was purely type and effects.

But I'm having a lot of issues with a select element within this form.

For whatever reason, a select element, which comes before a series of paired radio buttons (themselves grouped within fieldsets), is cutting off both the legend element and the label element for the first radio input. It looks like this:

[select element viewed w/ element picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPRaw.png)

It looks like content-box is taking up a ton of space. Or that space is "saved" for an active select dropdown? I'm not sure why there's so much blue there ^_^ I'm probably missing something very simple.

I've sectioned the select element off (using semantic section), I've wrapped it within its own row, I've tried applying some small-but-noticeable amount of extra margin-bottom (mb-4 for example).

None of this has worked. Here's my code for this particular section:

```
            <section class="col-8 col-md-4" id="recommend">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="select">Would you recommend your stay at the Aperture
                    Science computer-aided Enrichment Center?</label>
                <select class="form-control mb-5" name="select" id="select" required>
                    <option value="">-- Please select an option --</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="absolutely">Absolutely</option>
                    <option value="of_course">Of course!</option>
            </section>
```

Any ideas? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably end your `<select>` element, as this could have unknown effects on the rest of the DOM.

```
<select class="form-control mb-5" name="select" id="select" required>
                <option value="">-- Please select an option --</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="absolutely">Absolutely</option>
                <option value="of_course">Of course!</option>
</select> <!-- <- this was missing -->
```

Comment: This was exactly it... Wow. Sorry, VSCode wasn't giving me any errors and web browsers, as I understand, give you a lot of leniency in terms of how they compile what you wrote, even if it's wrong in some small but fundamental way.Thank you for your help. I'll need to consider combing through what I've written a little more thoroughly next time - I think something got lost when I started sectioning elements differently than I had originally and I just never noticed it again.